# Series of the form $\sum \frac {1}{{p_k}^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, irrational-numbers

Is it reasonable to expect that for every $n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{1\}$ the series $\sum \dfrac {1}{{(p_k)}^n}$ converges to an irrational number? Here, $p_k$ is $k$-th prime.

Are there any results in this direction?

Comment: Why does it converge at all?

Comment: As @uniquesolution said, there is no reason for this serie to converge, unless you make more assumptions on $p_k$. Let's consider $\forall k \in \mathbb N, p_k=2$. That's a sequence of prime, but you serie is not going to converge

Comment: Do you mean that $p_k$ is the $k$th prime?

Comment: $p_k>k$ shows convergence.

Comment: [Prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function) $$ \sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\log\left(\zeta(2n)\right)=0.45224742\dots $$

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that every number is irrational, with a set ofmeasure zero of exceptions. But for these particular numbers, no one knows how to prove irrationality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you mention in your question is the Prime Zeta function, defined as

$$
P(n)=\sum_{k>1} p_k^{-n}
$$

for $Re(n)>1$.

The irrationality of its values is still an open problem.